# Google Sheet with Google Finance lookup and custom function causes Google Drive to constantly resync

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a sheet with a Google Finance lookup:

`=googlefinance("USDZAR")`

and a custom function that returns a constant string (abc). It doesn't take any parameters:

`=test()`

See [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ji1vLyyzhSXZAoJoOTqh3Tux4jni6fDT65YtTzXaX1g/edit?usp=sharing)

Google Drive keeps syncing this sheet to my computer every 5-10 mins:

[image: Google Drive screenshot]

No actual content is being synced since Sheet files are only 176 bytes in size - they must be references to cloud data at Google:

[image: Sheet on filesystem]

I've compared subsequent files and they are identical.

Also, the Drive API keeps generating change events for this file every few minutes (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch)

It's definitely the combination of the Google Finance and custom function - either separately doesn't cause this.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? It seems like a bug?

Answer (score 0):

it's a "future" of **`GOOGLEFINANCE()`** to update in given intervals. it has nothing to do with your custom function.

and if **`GOOGLEFINANCE()`** constantly updating then it constantly syncing to your PC

you can try **`=GOOGLEFINANCE("USDZAR"; "daily")`** if that will do the trick, othervise you will need somehow to freeze **`GOOGLEFINANCE()`** formula

Comment: No, it's the combination. If I create a spreadsheet with ONLY the Google Finance formula, I do not get the continuous syncing.